# Why do I no longer have the question and answer editing privilege?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, edits, suggested-edits, privileges

Recently I've noticed that in Stack Overflow I no longer am allowed to edit questions and answers. This seems to be disabled. 
Can anyone please tell me why that might have happened?

Comment: The reason is given below, in the answer. The reason you're edit-banned is because you're making far too minor edits, as well as invalid edits. You don't need to put code highlighting around seemingly random, non-code words, for instance.

Comment: To make it short, you are misusing the backtick. It should be used for inline code, `not` just `random` key `words`.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Are you implying I'm longwinded? ;)

Comment: @J.Steen great minds think alike, in our case oscillating alike. :-D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Too many of your recent suggested edits have been rejected, and you have been banned (temporarily, one week) from suggesting any more.

Reviewing the recent rejected suggestions, we find:

- [February 27](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1611363)

  - You need to do more than just fix the formatting and remove 'thank you'. You left many other problems in place. It was thus rejected as Too Minor.

- [February 27](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1611353)

  - 'JavaScript', 'JSF' and 'API' are *not* code (or variable names). Don't use backticks for 
    those, only use that for code and names taken from code (class names, variables, etc.).

- [February 27](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1611304)

  - Just adding backticks to `JPanel` is too minor; adding the ticks doesn't really add anything to the quality of that post.

- [February 26](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1600606)

  - 'firefox', 'chrome' and 'internet explorer' are *not* code (or variable names). Don't use backticks for 
    those, only use that for code and names taken from code (class names, variables, etc.).

- [February 25](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1593828)

  - 'javascript' is *not* code (or a variable name). Don't use backticks for 
    those, only use that for code and names taken from code (class names, variables, etc.).

- [February 22](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1578995)

  - 'Worker Threads and SwingWorker' is *not* code (or a variable name). Don't use backticks for 
    those, only use that for code and names taken from code (class names, variables, etc.).

These two were editing conflicts (suggested edits always lose to a regular edit submitted at the same time):

- [February 25](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1594997)
- [February 25](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1594861)

The rest are older.

Your ban will automatically be lifted after 1 week, but its purpose has been served. You took a breather from suggesting edits and instead took the time to find out why you were blocked. Thank you!

Comment: Go through your list of suggested edits and see which ones have been rejected. Try to understand why. http://stackoverflow.com/users/1575570/nidhishkrishnan?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: One thing I can suggest, Nidhish; a number of your edits are just taking random 'key' words and using code formatting to emphasize them. You should not do that; Code formatting should only be used for actual code.

Comment: will this be permanent...

Comment: @AndrewBarber Whilst I agree with what you are suggesting, I disagree with that last sentence. I do find that if I'm speaking about class names, it's a lot better and more readable to put them in code. Although, this doesn't warrant an edit to an existing post, as others have stated :)

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan: No, just 1 week from the last edit. You did the right thing coming here to learn how to not have so many edits rejected in the future.

Comment: @mattytommo: I think that that is what Andrew means. There is, however, a tendency to put *anything* that sounds remotely 'code-ish' in backticks these days. See the second rejected suggestion.

Comment: @mattytommo I'm not really against *judicious* use of code formatting for class names. But this user was using it for things like `Javascript`

Comment: Thanks for all your replies.... Now i understand what the problem is...

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah I see, then I agree with the over-`using` of the `code` statement, I see it a lot in the `C#` questions. I mean, `while` it can be used `if` responsible, `using` it `for` every keyword is pretty `void` IMO :)

Comment: @Al: Thanks. Non-native speaker, still working on the muscle memory for those two...